# How can I add text to a Google Docs document via Docs API?

Tags: go, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to add text to an existing Google Docs file via Google Docs API and I'm using Golang for this. I followed steps in https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/go I can reach but I don't know how can I edit this file?

I found how to add text to file here is related part of my code :

```
b := &docs.BatchUpdateDocumentRequest{
        Requests: []*docs.Request{
            {
                InsertText: &docs.InsertTextRequest{
                    Text: "texttoadd",
                    Location: &docs.Location{
                        Index: md.Body.Content[len(md.Body.Content)-1].EndIndex - 1,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
    _, err = srv.Documents.BatchUpdate("your_document_id", b).Do()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `but I don't know how can I edit this file` and `I still couldn't solve the problem`? If an error occurs, please show it.

Answer (score 1):

this answer is a bit late:

1. the go api is now available [here](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/docs/v1#section-documentation):
2. regarding the specifics of your code, it should work. I added a step for step approach below. You have to create the structures first and then assign their pointers to the Request structure.

The long way code:

```
var batchreqs docs.BatchUpdateDocumentRequest    

var instxtreq docs.InsertTextRequest     

var txtloc docs.Location   

var breq docs.Request    

txtloc.Index = {your index}    

txtloc.SegmentID = "" // a bit superfluous    

instxtreq.Location = &txtloc   

instxtreq.Text = "your new text"    

breq.InsertText =&instxtreq   

var breqarray [1](*docs.Request)    

breqarray[0].InsertText = instxtreq   

breqslice = breqarray[:]

 batchreqs.Request = &breqslice    

// now you can do the BatchUpdate

 _, err = srv.Documents.BatchUpdate("your_document_id", &batchreqs).Do()

// the batch reqs must be a pointer to an existing batchupdaterequest structure
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at their documentation, you can see the [InsertTextRequest](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/docs/v1#InsertTextRequest)and that is probably what you are looking for.

Although the documentation doesn't give you any Go example, the API is similar in other languages: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/move-text

(I can't comment, that is why this is an answer).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I still couldn't solve the problem and I can't find even a code example with Golang, also I'm new at Golang.

Comment: @pangea, as I said, look at the examples from *other* languages, the API will not change much.